# Metodo Count de archivo tipo BYTE

Tags: c#, bootstrap, mvc, linq

Resulta que tengo un problema. No logro hacer el método `Count` en una query Linq.

Se trata de contar un dato definido como `BYTE` en la base de datos y no puedo mostrarlo en la vista, me devuelve `0`, `null` o todos los valores, pero no por ejemplo los `true`" ni `false`, me devuelve todo o nada. No me hace la sumatoria, por ejemplo que diga "son 16 true y 8 false"

Quiero devolverlo en mi vista con el:

**Vista**

```
var item in model @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rme_vigente (este es el dato byte))
```

Resulta que la query de Linq que tengo es la siguiente y pienso debe estar mal, si me devuelve los datos de la bbdd.

**Controlador**

```
public ActionResult Contaorcin() { 
    var Model = db.View_1.OrderByDescending(model => model.rme_vigente); 
    int count = Model.Count(); 
    return View(Model.ToList()); 
}
```

También, pienso que debí hacer un método `int i = 0;`

Comment: Añade tu código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Como te comenta @HectorLopez, no podemos ayudarte sin ver que código estas intentando, y una definición clara del problema. No entiendo por ejemplo que quiere decir _No logro hacer el método Count_.Te da algun error?

Comment: Denme un segundo!, quiero devolverlo en mi vista con el:

"vista"
var item in model
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.rme_vigente (este es el dato byte))
resulta que la query de linq que tengo es la siguiente y pienso debe estar mal, si me devuelve los datos de la bdd
      "Controlador"  
  public ActionResult Contaorcin()
        {

    var Model = db.View_1.OrderByDescending(model => model.rme_vigente);
            int count = Model.Count();

            return View(Model.ToList());
        }

tambien, pienso que debi hacer un metodo int i = 0; gracias!

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añada esa informacion, por otra parte @Html.DisplayFor(**modelItem** => **item**.rme_vigente) en teoria item deberia ser modelitem almenos que sea otra variable

Answer (score 0):

El byte lo transforma a objeto boleano.
usas entity framework?
Si es asi solo pon en la condicional lo siguiente

```
//suponemos que esta es tu referencia a tu tabla  
var tabla = dbo.Clientes.ToList();         
//suponemos que la variable se llama valido      
int resVerdaderos = tabla.Where(x=> x.valido).ToList().Count();  
int resFalsos = tabla.Where(x=> !x.valido).ToList().Count();
```

Saludos!

Comment: Asi es, me devuelve boleano, probare!, no uso entity.

Comment: @KonnAN has marcado esta respuesta como aceptada. Eso significa que resuelve tu problema, con lo que probablemente no recibiras mas respuestas. Estás seguro de ello?

Comment: @Pikoh, no, pase a llevarlo, no la he solucionado

Comment: @KonnAN si quieres agradecer al autor una respuesta, puedes votarla positivamente (eso puedes hacerlo con cualquier respuesta). Pero aceptar solo podrás aceptar una,asi que es mejor de que te asegures de que la respuesta es la que te soluciona el problema

Comment: Me dice "no se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo bool en bool

Comment: Intenta con un cast.

Comment: tabla.Where(x=> (bool)!x.valido).ToList().Count();

Comment: O directamente hazle un convert .. tabla.Where(x=> Convert.ToBoolean(x.valido)).ToList().Count();